# How can I send image in react-native-gifted-chat?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-gifted-chat

I want to send image in react-Native-Gifted-chat like sending text. I am novice in react-native.

I have already used react-native-image-picker for pick a image from physical device, now I am unable to render image in message[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the onSend method of GiftedChat with an object as a parameter. Just pass an object with image as key. For example

```
onSend({ image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving answer, but i am little confused, please can you describe how can i send image using on-send method . i am using renderActions() for handleImage ref.(https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1745), still i am not able to send image & render, i have also used renderMessageImage() for rendering image but i am not succeed. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

1. install this library first
2. then simply choose the file from the document picker
   use this function

   onAttatchFile = async () => {
   try {
   const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
   type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
   });

   ```
      // console.log(res);
      let type = res.name.slice(res.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      if (
        res.type == 'doc' ||
        res.type == 'application/pdf' ||
        res.type == 'image/jpeg' ||
        res.type == 'image/png' ||
        res.type == 'image/jpg' ||
        res.type == 'application/msword' ||
        type == 'docx'
      ) {
        this.setState({slectedFile: res}, () => this.onSendWithImage());
      } else {
        alert(`${type} files not allowed`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      //Handling any exception (If any)
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        //If user canceled the document selection
        // alert('Canceled from single doc picker');
      } else {
        //For Unknown Error
        // alert('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      }
    }
   ```

   };
3. use this function when you want to send the image

   ```
     onSendWithImage() {

    let imageData = {
      name: this.state.slectedFile.name,
      type: this.state.slectedFile.type,
      size: this.state.slectedFile.size,
      uri: this.state.slectedFile.uri,
    };
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type', 2);
    formData.append('senderId', this.state.senderData.id),
    formData.append('recieverId', this.state.reciverData._id),
    formData.append('message', imageData);


    post('sendMessage', formData).then(res =>

       res.success ? this.msjSendSuccess(res) : this.msjSendFailure(res),
    );
   ```

   }
4. talk with your backend and say to him /her to send the image in the image key
5. complete enjoy React native